# redis streams ordered processing within consumer groups

Tags: python, redis, stream, aioredis

I am using python (aioredis) with redis streams.

I have a one producer - many (grouped) consumer scenario and would like to ensure that the consumers are processing the (bulk) messages sent to a stream in an ordered fashion, meaning: when first message is done, process next message in the stream and so on. This would also mean that on of the consumer in the consumer group is processing at a time whereas the other consumers would wait.

I also want to rely on an ordered processing in a second, third and so on consumer group - all relying on the same messages sent to one stream. meaning:

```
message 1 ... n -> stream1 
ordered processing within group 1 ... n  
whereas consumer 1 ... n per group 1 ... n
```

What would be a good approach to get this done when I also want to ensure that there is not much overload with a potential order checking logic per group?

Comment: Why would you use consumer group if you want to process messages sequenctlally? Is this just for sharing message across multiple consumer groups?

Comment: I use consumer groups to apply different topic related to one message. For example - an order being sent to a stream by a producer 1) consumer group payment: process payment details 2) consumer group logistics: trigger delivery of goods 3) consumer group purchase: buy more goods to fill stock

Comment: What about retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get back to old school to synchronous processing, if you want to process stream messages sequentially it's not easy, the reasons are failure/retry.

Consider you want to process each message **at max once**, stream message execution is a critical section, and consumer group members as threads/processes.

To synchronize this, you need to have some sort of locking mechanism,  given consumer group could be running on different machines. You can use a global locking mechanism to prevent multiple consumers from consuming messages from the same stream.

You can use Redis lock (RedLock) to acquire/release the lock.

Psuedo Code

```
Procedure SequentialProcessor

Input: StreamName
Input: ConsumerName
Input: ConsumerGroup
Input: LockTime 


BEGIN
    redLock = RedLock()
    WHILE True DO
     IF redLock.aquireLock(StreamName#ConsumerGroup, LockTime) THEN
       message = redis.XREADGROUP( ConsumerGroup, StreamName, ...)
       TRY
         processMessage( message )
       FINALLY
          redLock.releaseLock( StreamName#ConsumerGroup )
     ENDIF
    END
END
```